# HTML / CSS Display fixed ratio images based on the height of the page

Tags: html, css, image, height, aspect-ratio

There is probably a relentlessly simple solution to this but I've been chasing my tail for a while so I've come to ask those wiser and smarter than me.

I've got a website for a personal project I'm making which displays images within a lightbox. See image: 
[image: desired layout]
The header area (red) is fixed height.

I want the images (yellow) to sit within a light box (green) which also has a caption. Crucially the images displayed need to retain their aspect ratio, 5:4, and fill the remaining height left below the header (bar a small margin top and bottom).

There's probably a really simple, elegant solution out there but I've not found it.

Any help gratefully received.

EDIT ---

Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/qh2V8/
Even this isn't right as I've had to put a fixed width in to even try and get it to work.

CSS:

```
#header{
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 145px;
background-color: #F00;
}

#overlayBg {
position: fixed;
top: 155px;
bottom: 20px;
padding: 8px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: #FF0;
width: 400px;
}

#overlayContainer img {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#overlayBg p {
position: relative;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="overlayBg">
    <div id="overlayContainer">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/u9VIg60.jpg" />
    </div>
    <p>Caption</p>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have code that you have built already so we can see what you are doing wrong?

Comment: How much height do you want to allow for the "Caption"? Will the caption text be a single line or multiple lines?

Comment: Are you making your own lightbox or are you using a 3rd party component, and if so, which one?

Comment: browsers try to stretch an image evenly. try using max-height css property, then set height: 100%

Comment: Cheers guys.

@eg_dac I've added code.

Comment: @MarcAudet One line. So just as much height as the text and maybe 5px either side. Own light box, just a div that's turned visible/hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where I got to.

There are fixed ratio solutions if you are basing the size of the element on width, using :before and padding-top. There's a good write up [here](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html).

There is a fixed ratio solution if you are basing the size of the element on height, however the height must be a % of the height of the screen. Written up here in another Stackoverflow question:
[Resize a Div Based on Height but Retain Aspect Ratio (almost got it) Strange Reload bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978774/resize-a-div-based-on-height-but-retain-aspect-ratio-almost-got-it-strange-rel)

If you have a fixed pixel size header or footer and need an element to expand to fill the exact size remaining you can't do it with just HTML and CSS.

Here's a codepen.io of where I got to:
http://codepen.io/niazipan/pen/ydkGt
JS to set the image height, and CSS to style everything else around it. Code below:

HTML

```
<div id="overlayBg">
  <div id="overlayContainer">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/u9VIg60.jpg" id="yourImgId" />
  </div>
  <p>Caption</p>
</div>
```

CSS
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

```
#header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #F00;
}

#overlayBg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 55px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #FF0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

#overlayContainer {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlayBg p {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

JS

```
var size = window.innerHeight - 120;
document.getElementById('yourImgId').style.height = size + 'px';
document.getElementById('overlayBg').style.width = size * 1.25 +'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

The image size need to be set through scripting, unless the images are a fixed constant size. The following link is of good help to your problem: [Change image size with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297449/change-image-size-with-javascript)
I'm pretty sure that you can get the original size of the image through yourImg.Style.Height and yourImg.Style.Width, and then make the calculations required to make it a 5:4 picture..